Why is Safari 17.5 requesting multiple image requests with img attributes srcset and sizes? Does not happen on Chrome or Firefox
Hello I have a simple html basic document that just requests an image based on the screen size:
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <img
        sizes="10vw"
        srcset="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624555130581-1d9cca783bc0?w=100 100w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624555130581-1d9cca783bc0?w=1000 1000w"
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624555130581-1d9cca783bc0"
        alt="name"
    />
</body>

When I look at my network for Safari 17.5 I can see it being requested 3 times uncached:

This behaviour does not happen on Chrome or Firefox.
Why is that?
I'm reading this and I'm pretty sure i'm doing it correctly:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images
